# Upload image "png"

Tags: php

Good morning all
I'm trying to upload an image to a folder but it doesn't take "png" images into account. Can you help me?

```php
if(isset($_POST["envoyer"]))
    {
        $extensions = array("jpg" => ".jpg", "jpeg" => '.jpeg', "gif" => '.gif', "png" => '.png', "pdf" => '.pdf');
        $extension = strrchr($_FILES['images']['name'], '.');
        $MonFichier=basename($_FILES['images']['name']);

        if(!in_array($extension,$extensions))
        {
            $erreur = '<font color="red">Vous devez Télécharger un fichier de type png, gif, jpg, jpeg </font><br>';
        }
        if(!isset($erreur)){
            //remplace des caractères dans une chaines
            $MonFichier = strtr($MonFichier,   "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ", "AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy");
            $MonFichier = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '-', $MonFichier);
            $name = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
            $filesize = $_FILES['images']['size'];
            $dossier='images/';
            // Vérifie la taille du fichier - 5Mo maximum
            $maxsize = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
            if($filesize > $maxsize) {
                echo $erreur='Image trop grande';
            }
            if(file_exists($dossier . $MonFichier))
            {
                echo "Cette image existe deja";
            }
            elseif(move_uploaded_file($name, $dossier . $MonFichier)){
            
            echo "Votre fichier a été téléchargé avec succès.";
            }
        
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Error: Il y a eu un problème de téléchargement de votre fichier. Veuillez réessayer.';
        }   
        
    }else
    {
        echo $erreur;
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what happens when you try?

Comment: Can you please provide more details?

Comment: the page turns but at the end the image does not load @aynber

Comment: @YT_Xaos The .png images do not load in my folder after I click "Send". the other images load well in my folder except the .png